# Which of them is the original Menthe Spicata (used for traditional Moroccon tea)?

Tags: identification, mint

I am a total newbie in gardening. Visited two shops on different days and bought menthe spicata used for traditional Moroccan tea. At home, I noticed that they are different plants. Made photos, which of them is the real menthe spicata?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one on the right is what I recognise as *Mentha spicata* or spearmint. I don't recognise the one on the left as a spearmint, not sure what it is - does it smell of mint when you bruise a leaf? If it does, it may well be a variety with the common name Chocolate Mint. There are images of various mint varieties here https://delishably.com/spices-seasonings/chocolate-mint-peppermint - chocolate mint is the fifth image.